# Nextpeer in Landscape only iphone game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, landscape, nextpeer

I used [Nextpeer](http://nextpeer.com/) in portrait game and works fine. Used same code in landscape game but Nextpeer dashboard coming still in portrait mode. How to change Nextpeer dashboard orientation to landscape?

Here is my Nextpeer initialisation code:

```
-(void)initializeNextpeer:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if([self internetConnected])
    {
        BOOL isRetina = (IS_IPAD) ? FALSE : TRUE ;

        NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                  // This game has no retina support - therefore we have to let the platform know
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:isRetina], NextpeerSettingGameSupportsRetina,
                                  // Support orientation change for the dashboard notifications
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], NextpeerSettingSupportsDashboardRotation,
                                  // Support orientation change for the in game notifications
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE], NextpeerSettingObserveNotificationOrientationChange,
                                  //  Place the in game notifications on the bottom screen (so the current score will be visible)
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:NPNotificationPosition_TOP], NextpeerSettingNotificationPosition,
                                  nil];

        [Nextpeer initializeWithProductKey:@"HERE_USED_NEXTPEER_KEY"
                               andSettings:settings
                              andDelegates:[NPDelegatesContainer containerWithNextpeerDelegate:self]];

        // Handle any notifications the game was launched with
        [Nextpeer handleLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    }
}
```

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mistakenly used the Potarit bundle provided by NExtPeer for different layouts.Please drag and drop Landscape bundle to your app.

For more info check this and look at step 3
[Next Peer Docs](http://developers.nextpeer.com/documentation/docs)